# How to disable the sorting axis option in Power BI line chart?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have some data coming from a SQL Server query and the table looks as shown in the next figure:

[image]

If I display this in an Excel chart, it looks like the following picture:
[image]

As it can be noticed, in Excel the chart displays the data according to the order they have in the table.
When I tried to show this data in a Power BI line chart, it looks like the following picture:
[image]

Because the data is sorted by the occupancy values.

I do not want the data sorted as Power BI does. I want the data in the same way they are in the table. Any ideas about how can I do to disable the sorting axis option?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-disable-sorting-in-Table-visual/td-p/1240794

Comment: are you familiar with sorting option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be rather simple.

Just click on the field that is currently used for the sorting, once you click it, the sort goes away completely.

See demo:

**Sort actived**:

[image: Sort Active]

**Sort deactivated** (clicking on `Count of Status)`:

[image: Sort deactivated]